# Uisng Python Parser of Field Calculator with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a point shapefile with two columns i want to process.
The first column is aspect and the second is aspect_m60, there is only one row with the aspect of my point. I have tried to write a script in Python for ArcGIS 10.2.2 because i want to put it in my code but with no success.
The code is this:

```
# Calculate Field
import arcpy
# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/W/Sik"
# Set local variables
inTable = "Point"
fieldName = "aspect_m60"
expression = "getCalc(!aspect!, !aspect_m60!)"
codeblock = """def getCalc(aspect, aspect_m60):
   if (aspect < 60):
      aspect_m60 = (aspect - 60) + 360
   if (aspect = 60):
      aspect_m60 = aspect - 60
   else:
      aspect_m60 = aspect - 60"""
```

Comment: Judging from the answers you've received and what hasn't yet worked for you, I think you should give a more detailed outline of how you're implementing this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is much more intuitive, in my opinion, to work with Cursors (rather than trying to emulate the field calculator in a script) for this type of problem.  This is how you would port the problem over to an [Update Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000):

```
import arcpy

# The input FC
fc = "C:/W/Sik.gdb/yourFC"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["aspect", "aspect_m60"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # row[0] = "aspect"
        # row[1] = "aspect_m60"
        if row[0] < 60:
            row[1] = (row[0] - 60) + 360
        elif row[0] == 60:
            row[1] = row[0] - 60
        else:
            row[1] = row[0] - 60

        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: thanks for your response unfortunately i don't have a gdb or mxd.

Comment: You can use a cursor on tables, feature classes or shapefiles.  Just replace the path with your own (e.g. `fc = "C:/W/Sik/Point.shp"` for a shapefile or `fc = "C:/W/Sik/Point.dbf"` for a .dbf table.

Comment: thank you i put it but i get an: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: __exit__

Comment: Sorry, I made an error in the "untested" script.  I needed to add `da` to the cursor function.  Please see the updated script.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to set the field within the code block, when actually you need the code block to `return` the value you're looking for.  If you just just add `return aspect_m60` after the else block, it should work fine.

Think of the code block as a place to write functions whose results can be used in your field calculator expression.

Comment: thanks for your response, where should i put return aspect_m60? at the last line ir in each command after if....:  ? cause i tried both but..

Answer (score 3):

Your function is not returning anything. I've modified your code to return the value of aspect_m60.

```
# Calculate Field
import arcpy
# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/W/Sik"
# Set local variables
inTable = "Point"
fieldName = "aspect_m60"
expression = "getCalc(!aspect!)"
codeblock = """def getCalc(aspect):
   if (aspect < 60):
      aspect_m60 = (aspect - 60) + 360
   if (aspect = 60):
      aspect_m60 = aspect - 60
   else:
      aspect_m60 = aspect - 60
   return aspect_m60"""
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i tried your code form python window and i didn't get a result in column aspect_m60

Answer (score 0):

As a couple others have pointed out, you're missing a return value. You're also confusing the assignment operator `=` for an equality operator `==` (in the 2nd if). The if structure is also incorrect (if/if/else), and will calculate the wrong value for anything less than 60 (should be if/elif/else).

If you still want to use CalculateField (the other answer with UpdateCursor is perfectly valid), the code block below would be what you intended.

```
codeblock = """def getCalc(aspect, aspect_m60):
    if aspect < 60:
        aspect_m60 = (aspect - 60) + 360
    elif aspect == 60:
        aspect_m60 = aspect - 60
    else:
       aspect_m60 = aspect - 60
    return aspect_m60
"""
```